# Issue with FileOutputStream in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I get a runtime exception when I execute the following code. I cannot see what is wrong.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileIO {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        File test = new File("test.txt");

        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(test); 

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(ostream);
    }
}
```

I keep getting a `FileNotFoundException`. I have tried keeping the file in every possible folder within the project and also tried giving an explicit path, but I keep getting the same exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any difference between compilation time and execution time?

Comment: @Jagger: File has all permissions enabled for all users.

Comment: @Jin From which language are you coming from? You should learn about checked and unchecked exceptions in Java.

Comment: So...you were getting a compile time error and not a runtime exception? sigh...

Answer (score 2):

When I tried this, it didn't even compile. I had to say that the main `throws FileNotFoundException`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class FileIO 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        File test = new File("test.txt");

        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(test); 

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(ostream);            
    }
}
```

This worked just fine with no errors

Comment: OK. This works. I hadn't read about throws keyword, so I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is undoubtedly that the current directory isn't what you think it is.

Add this line of code immediately after initializing the file variable:

```
System.out.println(test.getAbsolutePath());
```

The problem should be obvious.

Alternatively, specify an absolute path:

```
File test = new File("/mydir/test.txt");
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I had tried giving an explicit path, but it did not work. I had created a text file by this name in every folder in the heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the file `test.txt` in your current directory is readonly and an attempt to open it for writing (by instantiating a class of type `FileOutputStream`) is prohibited.

Check the file's permissions or delete it and run your program again (after adding a `try catch` block for the unhandled `FileNotFoundException` exception thrown by `FileOutputStream`.

For instance:

```
    try {
        ostream = new FileOutputStream(test);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(ostream); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and [FileOutputStream class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), try this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileIO {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        File test = new File("test.txt");

        if (test.exists()) {
            if (!test.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + test.getAbsolutePath() + " is not a regular file!");
                System.exit(1);
            } else if (!test.canWrite()) {
                System.out.println("Can not write to file " + test.getAbsolutePath() + "!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            test.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(test); 

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(ostream);
    }
}
```

This checks for the common error conditions.

- file exists
- file isn't a regular file
- file cannot be written to

Comment: new FileOutputStream() already does all those tests, in the kernel, atomically, and provides a message in the exception that says what the problem is if any. Repeating all those tests adds zero value, and it introduces timing-window problems as well. You still have to catch FileNotFoundException: why write all the handling code twice?

Comment: For a simple reason: The OP didn't know where his code was failing. I offered tests to catch the situations where the exception could have been thrown. I never recommended the above code for production code.

Comment: Of course, if his code wasn't even compiling, then the file isn't the issue, and none of this matters.

Comment: The text of the exception would have told him that, if there really had been an exception thrown , which there wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a runtime exception when I execute the following code.

No you didn't. You got a *compiler error message* when you tried to *compile* it. The message told you that new FileOutputStream throws FileNotFoundException and your code doesn't catch it. So fix your code to do that, or have main() declared as 'throws FileNotFoundException'.